# Octopress blog as rails subdirectory, with github public repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, octopress

I am successfully running my octopress blog as rails subdirectory. My blog's source is a public repository in github and i added this repository as submodule in my rails app.

My question is - is it ok to keep blog's source as public github repo ? I mean, is there any reason to keep blog's source as private ? My website is doing good business. Is it safe to keep blog as public repo ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database credential and other security credential file directory on gitignore file. It will keep secure your public repo. If you confused you can put your source on bitbucket private repo.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is correct site/way for this question. Still, trying to answer.

If it is commercial code, you should go for `private` repo.

If you want to make it public, it will be visible to all. If you are okay with it, go for `public` and add your credential files, secure keys etc into `.gitignore`.

As I can understand that you are not sure about your code licensing, I would recommend you to use [`www.gitlab.com`](http://www.gitlab.com) to make your repos **private for FREE**.

Comment: "If you want to make it public, it will be open source and others can use it for their needs." This is absolutely not true. Code is only open source if it has been explicitly licensed that way. Being able to see the code on GitHub (or anywhere else) is not a license to use it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007674/whats-the-default-license-of-code-published-at-github, for example.